# Material UI: Checkbox in Functional Component, am I missing something?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have found articles on SO on using the Material UI Checkbox component in a class-based React component, but I am struggling to get it working in a functional component. Which is strange, since the documentation from Material UI uses functional components.

I am trying to follow their documentation as closely as possible but I can't seem to get the Checkbox's handleChange to fire. The checkbox doesn't change, but as far as I can tell my code is the same as the first example on the docs here: https://material-ui.com/components/checkboxes/

Here is my component:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import CardHeader from "@material-ui/core/CardHeader";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  card: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column"
  },
  header: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row"
  },
  content: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    flex: "2"
  },
  cover: {
    display: "flex"
  },
  avatar: {
    width: "100px"
  },
  large: {
    width: theme.spacing(7),
    height: theme.spacing(7)
  }
}));

const SelectSpeciesCard = ({ speciesImg, speciesGeneralName }) => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(true);

  const handleChange = event => {
    // <-- Can't get this to work
    console.log("Checkbox checked");
    setChecked(event.target.checked);
  };

  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  return (
    <Card className={classes.card}>
      <CardHeader
        className={classes.header}
        avatar={<Avatar src={speciesImg} className={classes.large} />}
        action={
          <Checkbox
            checked={checked}
            value="secondary"
            color="primary"
            inputProps={{ "aria-label": "secondary checkbox" }}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        }
        title={speciesGeneralName}
      />
    </Card>
  );
};

export default SelectSpeciesCard;
```

Comment: Copy/pasted your code into a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/currying-frost-9r26g?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark), it works. Are there any errors? What is happening? What are you seeing?

Comment: Thanks for helping out, @DrewReese. The checkbox remains checked, it doesn't change. I even copied your code from the sandbox exactly to see what would happen and it just does not update the Checkbox. I see you've added useState and useEffect, I've also tried adding those to no avail. 

What I did notice when adding your useEffect, I now get a console log for each time the card is rendered.

Nothing happens when I click the Checkbox though, which I can't seem to understand, see here: http://www.giphy.com/gifs/IbkpnzLMZrmdcY7VLs

Comment: Sorry that Gif doesn't work, it just shows me clicking the checkbox and it remaining checked anyway.

Comment: One more note, don't know if this helps, but I am rendering instances of this component from a class-based parent component and passing down props to display the data, not sure if that may be causing it?

Comment: Do you mind sharing that code then, here or in another code sandbox?

Comment: Thank you for taking such an interest, I've added both those files to a sandbox here. https://codesandbox.io/s/white-dew-ljn8n?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I obviously can't connect my actual firebase to this sandbox, but just know that the parent loops through an array of objects with that .map function, and that works. It's just that Checkbox that's not, well Checking ;)

Comment: I've created another [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-browser-k5wfd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) that I think pieces together your UI, but it isn't connected to any of your app state code. The checkbox toggles are working for me. Are you driving their `checked` value from your application state (redux) and somehow it isn't getting updated? or do you always use the `SelectSpeciesCard` local state (what the sandbox does and is working for me)?

Comment: Hi Drew, yes it has something to do with redux, if I do it locally as in your example here, it works perfectly. I have decided to just use a class-based component instead, where I can easily use local state to just manage the checkbox and it is working nicely now. Sorry for the run-around :) Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Ok. no worries. I'm curious though, html input elements have their own internal state, so if you're using your redux state to drive the checked values, using class-based or functional components is irrelevant. I updated the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-browser-k5wfd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) again with a redux pattern. This important change to note now is the local `checked` state within `SelectSpeciesCard` is now removed. The idea being you want a single source of truth for app state, there's no need to duplicate it in local state within components.

Comment: Drew, I have managed to get it working with your example code above and keeping one state, so THANK YOU :) Have a great weekend!